# how can I pass a dynamic array to a kernel module in linux?

Tags: module, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, dynamic-programming

I'm writing a kernel module in c language and I want to pass a dynamic array to it, but I can't figure it out.
I have tried allocating dynamic array like how we did it in C but it's not working yet.

I tried:

```
int * arr; 
module_param(arr ,int ,NULL ,0);
```

but compiler tells that given code is incorrect.

How can I pass a dynamic array to my kernel module through commnadline?

Comment: what interfaces/code do you have?

Comment: nothing important actually, I just have a kernel module that prints the elements of the array passed to it.

Comment: youd need to provide a bit more than that, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Parsa: Show example of *user space* code, which could generate a dynamic array in question. Show *kernel space* code, which works with a dynamic array. `I have tried allocating dynamic array like how we did it in C but it's not working yet.` - Show what have you tried.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ```int *arr;
module_param(arr ,int ,NULL ,0);```

Comment: Well, so you tried to apply `module_param`. Add this code with some explanations to the **question post**, so it will be self-contained. Also in the question post describe what **exactly** is not worked (what error do you get, or so).

Comment: @Tsyvarev it's not working when I `make` it.giving error that the following code is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, the code is incorrect. If you check [macro's definition](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h#L128), you will see that it expects `the variable to alter` as the first parameter, not a pointer. That is, you should have definition `int arr;`. But this, of course, is a single value, not an array. Again, **what kind of user-kernel interface** do you want to pass a "dynamic array"? What should write a user, and how the kernel should interpret this. Describe that in the **question post**, not in the comments.

Comment: You may check [module_param_array](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h#L431) macro. While it requires array to be preallocated for maximum number of elements, actual number of elements is dynamic. Something like `int arr[10]; unsigned int num; module_param_array(arr, int, &num, 0644);`.